# How can I modify the Impression Region name?

Tags: marketing-cloud, reporting, content-builder, dynamic-content

I just enabled the Impression Tracking functionality in my account. I am creating an email to test it using Dynamic Content blocks but I dont see how can I change the Impression Region Name. Apparently I should be able to do it based on the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_impression_region_dynamic.htm&type=5) but I don't know how.

In the code view of the email I see it is automatically created when the Dynamic Content Block is created. For example:

```
%%=BeginImpressionRegion("01__Rule_1__benefits-fleurop.jpg")=%%
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how the BeginImpressionRegion function looks like:

```
BeginImpressionRegion(1)
```

Where "1" is a string that specifies the name of the Impression Region to track.

That said, you just need to replace "01__Rule_1__benefits-fleurop.jpg" with the name you would like to see in tracking. Here's an example from the ampscript.guide:

```
%%=BeginImpressionRegion("PrimaryNavigation")=%%

<a href="https://limedash.com/shop" alias="Shop">Shop</a> |
<a href="https://limedash.com/contact" alias="Shop">Contact</a>

%%=EndImpressionRegion(0)=%%
```

Read more here: https://ampscript.guide/beginimpressionregion/

**EDIT:**

From the UI you can change it when you define the content:

[image]

[image]

Comment: But this is in case I create a dynamic content using ampscript. But I am doing it using the Dynamic Content Block. Am I right?

Comment: I have updated my answer with a screenshot of how to change it form UI

Comment: I dont see where it is in the UI? Is it in the block settings of the dynamic content? If yes, I dont have that option

Comment: I added another screenshot - if you don't see this option, reach out to support.

Comment: Support replied: "I checked with my internal team on this issue to modify the Impression Tracking. Unfortunately, you cannot modify and doesn't give any option to modify.

Since this could be important to your organization, we encourage you to promote this at IdeaExchange."

Comment: Okay it is now enabled. Thanks!

Comment: The AMPScript function will not error out on the length of the string passed into BeginImpressionRegion("")

However, when the data gets recorded in Marketing Cloud, it only allows 60 characters so it will be truncated for reporting.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_sendimpression.htm&type=5